# Excel UDF is returning #value! when changing worksheets and copying and pasting

Tags: vba, excel, user-defined-functions

I have a sheet that has a table on it, the following function will be used to search another sheet and return the number of times the agents name shows up;

The problem I'm having is that if I try to copy and paste the value it will change from a number to '#Value!'. Also, when switching worksheets and then switching back to the worksheet that has the UDF being called it changes all values to '#Value!'

Here is the function and how it is called. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
Public Function GetMatrixCount(AgentName As String) As Integer
Dim matrixSheet As Worksheet, mContainer() As String, c As Integer, m As Integer, y As Integer
Dim fullRange As Range, l As Range, lastRow As Integer
Dim firstThree As String, curAgent As String

'toDo
'return zero if the matrix updates worksheet doesn't exist or the input string is empty
On Error Resume Next
Set matrixSheet = Sheets("Matrix Updates")
On Error GoTo 0
If matrixSheet Is Nothing Or Not Trim(AgentName) <> "" Then
    GetMatrixCount = 0
    Exit Function
End If

'get month number user wants to input from the title at the top of the page - used to do value check on matrix updates data
mContainer() = Split(Range("B1").Value, " ")
m = month(DateValue(mContainer(UBound(mContainer) - 1) & " 1"))
y = mContainer(UBound(mContainer))
firstThree = Left(AgentName, 3)
lastRow = matrixSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
c = 0

Set fullRange = matrixSheet.Range("B2:B" & lastRow)
For Each l In fullRange.Cells
    curAgent = l.Offset(0, 1).Value
    If month(l.Value) = m And year(l.Value) = y And Left(curAgent, 3) = firstThree And Mid(curAgent, InStrRev(curAgent, " ") + 1) = Mid(AgentName, InStrRev(AgentName, " ") + 1) Then
        c = c + 1
    End If
    If l.Value = "" Then
        Exit For
    End If
Next

GetMatrixCount = c
End Function
```

Usage:
=GetMatrixCount(B4)

B4: John Doe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPD:**
Try to write following:

```
Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set matrixSheet = wb.Sheets("Matrix Updates")
```

It should fix the problem when you switch workbooks.

Comment: This is to get the name of the month; cell B2 holds a string like: "Stats Sheet - DECEMBER 2012"; so I split the string to the mContainer variable and get the second to last work (December) and add convert it to the month so I can compare it to the month in the data field; hope that answers your question

Comment: Yea, that seems to have fixed the issue the #value! when changing workbooks.

I am still getting #Value! when copying and paste value. But this alone is a big help.

Comment: Have you tried to debug the function and see in what place error is occeured?

Comment: I don't think I know what you mean when you say debug. I have tried to ad several debug.print items in the function but I don't get any errors/problems when the #value! happens. I will add some more and check again

Comment: I figured it out. when the value gets pasted it gets recalculated. the reference on `mContainer() = Split(Range("B1").Value, " ")` was a relative reference and when I was copying the data to another sheet it was trying to go to the sheet B1 instead of the source sheet.

I added a reference to the source sheet and now it is all good.

`mContainer() = Split(Sheets("Scorecard").Range("B1").Value, " ")`

Comment: Cool:) I thought about this, but I don't know that you copy wrom one to _another sheet_ )